# Is there a simple way to send many emails that fit a template?

Tags: email, mutt

I have a `csv` file `~/data.csv` whose content looks like this:

```
| name            | email                   | code |
|-----------------+-------------------------+------|
| Lennon,John     | john40@beatles.fake     |   37 |
| McCartney,Paul  | paul42@beatles.fake     |   99 |
| Harrison,George | harrison43@somesite.com |   43 |
| Starr,Ringo     | starr40@someschool.edu  |   84 |
```

I'd like to send an email to each person listed in this csv file. Each email
should be of the form:

```
<NAME>,

Your code is: <CODE>


Best,

me
```

Is there a simple way to do this? I have neomutt configured on my system, so maybe
there is a solution with neomutt?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a shell/awk/perl script to parse your CSV, and then use variables inside an `echo | mutt`.